# Load custom file in jquery returns error even though file is loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webgl

I have the following code in order to load a `.glsl` file

```
$.getScript("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl", function( vertexShader ) {
    console.log(vertexShader);
});
```

The content of the `vertexShader.glsl` is:

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;  
precision highp int;

out vec3 world_coords;
void main()
{
    world_coords = position + vec3(0.5);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

Even though everything seems to work properly I retrieve the following error:

```
VM598:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at m (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery.min.js:2)
at Ut (jquery.min.js:2)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The code is working fine, but I still get the errors. Any ideas how to get rid of them?

Comment: `$.getScript(".../vertexShader.glsl",`. Why are you using three dots?

Comment: I just did not want to show the whole path! Made it more clear.

Comment: This method is supposed to load javascript files.

Comment: Okay, what other methods would you use?

Answer (score 1):

`$.getScript` loads JavaScript scripts. Unlike internal scripts, scripts where the content is inside HTML, You can not use an external script to load anything other than JavaScript.

To load a text file the modern easy way use fetch and async/await

```
async function main() {
  const vertexShader = await fetch("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl").then(req => req.text());
  ...
}
main();
```

or of course turn it into a function

```
async function main() {
  const vertexShader = await loadText("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl");
  ...
}

function loadText(url) {
  return fetch("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl").then(req => req.text());
}

main();
```

or without async/await

```
fetch("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl")
  .then(req => req.text())
  .then(function( vertexShader ) {
    console.log(vertexShader);
  });
```

or if you want it to look similar to `getScript`

```
getTextFile("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl", function( vertexShader ) {
  console.log(vertexShader);
});

function getTextFile(url, callback) {
  fetch("path/to/file/vertexShader.glsl")
    .then(req => req.text())
    .then(callback);
}
```

that said, if it was me and I wanted my shaders to be external I'd use `import` / `export` as in

```
// myvertexshader.glsl
default export `
  attribute vec4 position
  void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
  }
`;
```

And then you can `import` that into another javascript module as in

```
// main.js
import vertexShader from './myvertexshader.glsl';
...
```

main.js needs to be included as a module

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

`import` only works on modern browsers (like the kind that run WebGL2) but you can use something like [rollup](https://www.google.com/search?q=rollup.js) to convert it back into an old style single file JavaScript file.

This has the advantage that during development all your files are separate but for production/deployment you can build your JavaScript into one large file which will load much faster than many small files

[three.js does this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk) if you'd like to see an example

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that the `export default` option is neat, but what bothers me is that there is no syntax highlighting ...

Comment: apparently you can do something like `default export /* glsl */ \`code\`;` in some editors and get it to syntax highlight. I haven't looked into it. If you look at the Three.js files they have that kind of comment at the top so maybe [ask them](https://discourse.threejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I haven't fully understand if You need to append the `glsl` scripts to the `head` of Your html page for later reuse, but if Your program is actually compiling fine and You just only need to get rid of that errors, then the solution is simple.

The `$.getScript` is just a shorthand for the full  Ajax function, so use that and specify the script type:

```
function getScript() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./solid.vert",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result){
            // Inside result is the vertex shader
        }
    });
}
```

BTW, I am using the extension `.vert` for vertex shaders and `.frag` for fragment shaders, whereby the `MIME` type on the server is set to `text/plain`.